# SQLAlchemy update neither works nor raises errors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update the `email` column of the `user` table where `id == 3`. Below code does not update any rows or even raise any errors. Where could the problem be?

```
from sqlalchemy import update
@app.route('/testupdate/')
def testupdate():
    stmt = update(user).where(user.id==3).values(email='a@b')
    db.session.commit()
    return 'done'
```

Comment: try this - session.query(User). filter(User.id == 3).update({"email": "a@b"})

Comment: Got this error: `AttributeError: 'NullSession' object has no attribute 'query'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no SQL was emitted to the database.

```
    stmt = update(user).where(user.id==3).values(email='a@b')
```

Does not actually execute the statement, it just creates it. To actually execute it you have to pass it to

```
    db.session.execute(stmt)
```

and then commit. You could also instead just use the [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) API of the session:

```
    db.session.query(user).\
        filter_by(id=3).\
        update({user.email: 'a@b'},
               synchronize_session='evaluate')
```

Note that depending on whether or not you have the affected instances in the session and will be using them later on you could choose not to synchronize at all with `False`.

Comment: And you're 100% sure you have a `user` in your DB with the id *3*? Also consider setting `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` in your configuration and check that the SQL is actually sent to the DB, i.e. your code runs.

Comment: Yes there is a user table with id 3 in database and also `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` has been set to `True` already.

Comment: And you're seeing the `UPDATE` being executed (followed by `COMMIT`)? Other than that there's nothing wrong with your code (except the missing `execute()` in the original). If you're observing the `UPDATE`, then the error is elsewhere (wrong DB for example...). Perhaps you should try writing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which the question is not at the moment. While writing that you might even find the issue.

Comment: I used this and it updates email column but of all rows `db.session.execute(update(puser, values={puser.email: "za@bcdef"}))` and 'db.session.commit()' How can I update where id=3?

Comment: `db.session.execute(update(puser, values={puser.email: "za@bcdef"}).where(puser.id == 3))` or any of the previous methods.